# Default textarea value in angularjs when textarea is bound to model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML:

```
<textarea ng-model="user.ban_reason"></textarea>
```

Initially the ban reason is empty. However I want to provide a default value. But

```
<textarea ng-model="user.ban_reason">reason</textarea>
```

Does not work.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: How about using a `placeholder`? -- http://jsfiddle.net/Xxqnr/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside your controller you can do as below:

```
$scope.user = {
    ban_reason:"reason"
}
```

Comment: Hm actually I don't wont to do this in controller, we should keep this in view. Any idea how to do this in view?

Comment: Your view **should not** contain any data. If you just want to hint/guide the user, use a `placeholder` as [tymeJV](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1686485/tymejv) suggested in the OP comments.

Answer (score 5):

Well if there is a situation you still need it to have default text in the template, then you can use ng-init.

```
  <textarea ng-model="text" ng-init="text = 'Hello, this is my default text.'"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your angular app initializes when the documents DOM is ready - thus, overrides the value with your `$scope.user.ban_reason` value.

In your controller, define a default value for the model property:

```
$scope.user = { ban_reason: 'reason' };
```